# Error lists that are quite similar, concerning Missing assembly reference

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following errors. I suspect that they are related. Anyone have any idea what is wrong ??

1. Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'GoogleMapProject.ViewModel' that is not included in the assembly.
2. Undefined CLR namespace. The 'clr-namespace' URI refers to a namespace 'GoogleMapProject.Behaviors' that is not included in the assembly.
3. The type 'vm:MainViewModel' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
4. The type 'ei:FluidMoveBehavior' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
5. The type 'Behaviors:ZoomBehavior' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
6. The type 'Behaviors:PanBehavior' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
7. The type 'Behaviors:DisplayVideoBehavior' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.
8. The attachable property 'EaseY' was not found in type 'FluidMoveBehavior'.
9. The attachable property 'EaseX' was not found in type 'FluidMoveBehavior'.

1 Warning:
1. The tag 'FluidMoveBehavior' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions'. Line 23 Position 14.

Answer (score 0):

You either don't have a properly referenced library (GoogleMapProject) containing these things, have a wrong version, or these things aren't properly imported to your XAML using the `xmlns:` syntax.

This could be due to opening an existing project that has been 'cleaned', not coming with dependencies and the dependencies not being accessible from their original referenced location in order to copy over.

Comment: How to check whether i have a properly referenced library? Sorry I'm new to WPF...